# format date when taken from a constructor

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to format the date right but get an error message when i try it.

**My code:**

```
var dateText = document.getElementById("text");
        var dateDiv = document.createElement("div");
        dateDiv.id = "tid";
        dateDiv.innerHTML = MessageBoard.messages[messageID].getDateText();
        text.appendChild(dateDiv);
```

**And in another .js file:**

```
    this.getDate = function() {
        return date;
    };

    this.setDate = function(_date) {
        date = _date;
    };

/.../

Message.prototype.getDateText = function() {
    return this.message.getDate().toLocaleTimeString();
};
```

But i got an error message that says: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getDate' of undefined"

To get the date with just getDate works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, since you didn't post enough code to tell for sure:

```
return this.getDate().toLocaleTimeString();
```